# Converting "broken pipe" character from ASCII to EBCDIC for Java/Legacy Implementation

Tags: java, ascii, ebcdic

Working on an application that sends a a formatted IMS message to a legacy application via MQ/OTMA.  The broken pip character is required for the IMS transaction header.

We have tried to use the proper encoding for the broken-pipe but once received by the legacy transaction it is never translated properly.

The hex value for the broken-pipe in EBCDIC is x'6A'.  Which should be ASCII 'j' (value 106).  When added to the message, this value corrupts the message key field by adding several non-displayable character.

Is there a better way to encode the pipe character within the message?

Comment: What java code are you using ???. Are you `1)` sending ascii to MQ  `2)` sending EBCDIC to MQ.`3)` sending Java (2 byte unicode) Characters to MQ ??? If sending EBCDIC bytes you could just send x'6A'. Note: x'6a' = 106

Comment: A bit late but ASCII to EBCDIC depends upon code pages. As this was legacy it was probably IBM037 (US), but you might have also seen IBM500 International. The NOT and the BROKEN PIPE are often mangled.  https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/conversion-character-differences-between-ccsid-037-and-ccsid-500

Answer (score -1):

Don't think it is j, may be it is |. For Example in Charset ISO-8859-1 it is Character 7C.